# R intersect data.frame on multiple criteria

Tags: r, memory, intersect, sqldf

I am trying to populate a binary vector based on the intersection of two data.frames on multiple criteria.

I have the code working but I feel that it is memory excessive just to get the binary vector.

When I apply my code to my full data (40mm+ rows). I begin to have memory problems.

Is there a simpler way to produce the vector?

Here is some sample data (e.g., sub sample will only include obs. in full sample):

```
ob1_1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1999),c("111","222","666","777")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob2_1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2000),c("111","333","555","777")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob3_1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2001),c("111","222","333","777")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob4_1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2002),c("111","444","555","777")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

full_sample <-  rbind(ob1_1,ob2_1,ob3_1,ob4_1)
colnames(full_sample) <- c("yr","ID")

ob1_2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1999),c("111","222","777")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob2_2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2000),c("333")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob3_2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2001),c("888")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob4_2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2002),c("111","444","555","777")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

sub_sample <-  rbind(ob1_2,ob2_2,ob3_2,ob4_2)
colnames(sub_sample) <- c("yr","ID")
```

Here is my working code:

```
q_intersect <- ""
q_intersect <- paste(q_intersect , "select       a.yr, a.ID       ", sep=" ")
q_intersect <- paste(q_intersect , "from         full_sample a  ", sep=" ")
q_intersect <- paste(q_intersect , "intersect                     ", sep=" ")
q_intersect <- paste(q_intersect , "select       b.yr, b.ID       ", sep=" ")
q_intersect <- paste(q_intersect , "from         sub_sample b  ", sep=" ")
q_intersect <- trim(gsub(" {2,}", " ", q_intersect ))

intersect_temp <- cbind(sqldf(q_intersect ),1)
colnames(intersect_temp ) <- c("yr","ID","in_both")

q_expand <- ""
q_expand <- paste(q_expand , "select       in_both            ", sep=" ")
q_expand <- paste(q_expand , "from         full_sample a      ", sep=" ")
q_expand <- paste(q_expand , "left join    intersect_temp  b  ", sep=" ")
q_expand <- paste(q_expand , "on           a.yr=b.yr          ", sep=" ")
q_expand <- paste(q_expand , "and          a.ID=b.ID          ", sep=" ")
q_expand <- trim(gsub(" {2,}", " ", q_expand ))

solution <- as.integer(sqldf(q_expand)[,1])
solution [is.na(solution )] <- 0
```

Thanks ahead of time for any help!

Comment: You should explain what you want in natural language. (The code you say is working just locked up my session of R, possibly because there is no `trim` function?) No, the first `sqldf` call locks it up.

Comment: @Dwin, I just had the same lockup issue.  But only within the first 4 lines of the `q_intersect` portion.   Incidentally, Brad, in your previous question you were using `data.table` and here you are using `data.frame`.  Is this deliberate?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Hi. Have just untagged data.table. See discussion in chatroom yesterday which corrected me. Might do a larger untagging sweep. The SO view is that tags are for questions not answers. With fresh eyes, I now see and agree that the search "[data.table] data.table is:question" is what "[data.table]" alone should look like. However it seems ok (see chat) to tag accepted answers using `data.table` where votes>10 as well. To search for answers using data.table we can use "[r] -[data.table] data.table is:answer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not altogether clear what you are trying to accomplish, but I believe something like this would be a lot simpler.

```
library(data.table)
fullDT <- data.table(full_sample, key=c("yr", "ID"))
subDT  <- data.table(sub_sample,  key=c("yr", "ID"))

fullDT[ , intersect := 0L]
fullDT[subDT, intersect := 1, nomatch=0]
```

The idea is that you set the `key` of each `data.table` to be the columns you want to intersect.  When you call `full[sub], nomatch=0]` you get your inner join,  and we set only those values to `1`;  the values not identified in the inner join are left as `0`, as set in the line prior.

```
fullDT
#        yr  ID intersect
#   1: 1999 111         1
#   2: 1999 222         1
#   3: 1999 666         0
#   4: 1999 777         1
#   5: 2000 111         0
#   6: 2000 333         1
#   7: 2000 555         0
#   8: 2000 777         0
#   9: 2001 111         0
#  10: 2001 222         0
#  11: 2001 333         0
#  12: 2001 777         0
#  13: 2002 111         1
#  14: 2002 444         1
#  15: 2002 555         1
#  16: 2002 777         1
```

Comment: Ricardo,  this looks good.  I was using data.frames to create the sample data, but I prefer data.tables when possible.

Comment: This is definitely much simpler than my approach.  Thanks you again!

Comment: @Brad, no prob at all.  I was asking in my comments above, simply because it makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: You could speed this up by setting `intersect :=0` for the whole dataset (before setting the subset that joins to `1`).

Comment: @RicardoSaporta -- you might need to reword your description slightly as well.

Comment: @mnel, thanks again. Just edited (I'm working form my iPad, but it should be all correct now)

Answer (score 2):

**Simpler SQL**  I gather that you wish to create a one column data frame with the same number of rows as `full_sample` such that a given row in the output contains 1 if the corresponding row in `full_sample` has a matching `sub_sample` row and 0 otherwise.

In that case, the multiple SQL statements can be condensed into a single simpler SQL statement as shown below. The left join ensures that all rows of `full_sample` are included and the natural join causes the join to occur on all column names that are common between the two input data frames.

```
sqldf("select s.yr is not null as solution 
       from full_sample f natural left join sub_sample s")
```

(By the way, note that string literals can flow over multiple lines as this shows so its not necessary to paste multiple lines together.)

**Out of Memory Database** sqldf by default uses an in memory database but you can specify a file name (which need not exist ahead of time) via the `dbname=` argument to use as as out of memory database.  In that case you won't be limited by memory.

```
sqldf("select s.yr is not null as solution 
       from full_sample f natural left join sub_sample s", dbname = "mydb")
```

(Also you can improve performance in some cases by using indexes.  See the [sqldf home page](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) for examples.)

UPDATE:  added simpler sql solution